# Nginx try and serve from two different directories

Tags: nginx

I am trying to serve a wordpress application and a static site from two separate folders located inside the web-root folder.

```
/usr/local/nginx/html <- Root
/usr/local/nginx/html/application/wordpress/wordpress-files*
/usr/local/nginx/html/files/static-site-files*
```

Goal: I want to prioritise the files in /application/ and look in there first before trying /files/. If the file is not found in /application/, look and serve from /files/.

I've been reading up on try_files and it seems to be the way to go, but I have been unsuccessful.

I have tried the following location block...

```
    location / {
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            root /usr/local/nginx/html;
            try_files /application$uri /application$uri/ /files$uri /files$uri/ =404;
    }
```

That *mostly* works but there are a few issues.

If i visit http://serverip.com/wordpress/, the wordpress site shows, but if i visit http://serverip.com/wordpress, it redirects to /application/wordpress/.

Another issue is that if I visit http://serverip.com, I get a forbidden error due to nginx trying to list a directory when it is not allowed.
I understand why this is occurring, ( **/application$uri/** looks for an index file that is not there, so it tries to display the directory, rather than moving on to /files$uri) but this is not the behaviour I want. I want nginx to fall back to looking in /files/.

Is try_files suitable for my use-case?

Thanks

Comment: `/files$uri/ /files$uri/` assumed to be `/files$uri /files$uri/`. `try_files` is context sensitive...

Comment: Ah typo. Edited. Thanks

Comment: You could just use `location = /` and `location = /wordpress` to specify exactly what should be done for those two specific edge cases.

Comment: Could location be used with dynamic folder naming?